# Windows 10 evaluation shutdown so fast I can't re-install the full version

Tags: windows-10

I'm installing Windows 10 LTSC full to replace my Windows 10 LTSC trial. But the trial is expired, and my computer automatically shutdown after one hour. Problem is, it cannot install fast enough, and will shutdown before the installation reach 90%

The automatic shutdown is a feature of Windows 10 trial after it is expired. I tried "slgmr -rearm" to reset the trial time, but for some reason it's still expired.

Therefore my question is: How to install Windows 10 fast enough?

Comment: Also, I don't have an USB :(

Comment: I'm not familiar with how LTSC and Enterprise editions work, but with regular single-user editions you're not supposed to upgrade to a full version by installing it - you just enter your license details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply active Windows won't work, here is how I installed it:

Download and extract the Windows ISO file to a folder (make sure it's the full version). You should write the folder directory down.

Open Settings >> Update & Security >> Recovery >> Restart now >> Advanced options >> Command Prompt

Run `cd /d DRIVE:`. Replace DRIVE with the drive name the folder is in. I put it in drive C, so in my case: `cd /d C:`

Run `cd DIR`. Replace DIR with the correct directory you just wrote down

Run `setup.exe`. You'll install Windows like normal